# Parsing a tab delimited file into separate lists or strings

Tags: python, parsing, tabs, delimited

I am trying to take a tab delimited file with two columns, Name and Age, which reads in as this:

'Name\tAge\nMark\t32\nMatt\t29\nJohn\t67\nJason\t45\nMatt\t12\nFrank\t11\nFrank\t34\nFrank\t65\nFrank\t78\n'

And simply create two lists, one with names (called names, without heading) and one with the ages (called ages, but without ages in the list).

Answer (score 20):

Using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv), you might do something like this:

```
import csv

names=[]
ages=[]
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    next(f) # skip headings
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for name,age in reader:
        names.append(name)
        ages.append(age) 

print(names)
# ('Mark', 'Matt', 'John', 'Jason', 'Matt', 'Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank')
print(ages)
# ('32', '29', '67', '45', '12', '11', '34', '65', '78')
```

Answer (score 10):

tab delimited data is within the domain of the `csv` module:

```
>>> corpus = 'Name\tAge\nMark\t32\nMatt\t29\nJohn\t67\nJason\t45\nMatt\t12\nFrank\t11\nFrank\t34\nFrank\t65\nFrank\t78\n'
>>> import StringIO
>>> infile = StringIO.StringIO(corpus)
```

pretend `infile` was just a regular `file`...

```
>>> import csv
>>> r = csv.DictReader(infile, 
...                    dialect=csv.Sniffer().sniff(infile.read(1000)))
>>> infile.seek(0)
```

you don't even have to tell the csv module about the headings and the delimiter format, it'll figure it out on its own

```
>>> names, ages = [],[]
>>> for row in r:
...     names.append(row['Name'])
...     ages.append(row['Age'])
... 
>>> names
['Mark', 'Matt', 'John', 'Jason', 'Matt', 'Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank', 'Frank']
>>> ages
['32', '29', '67', '45', '12', '11', '34', '65', '78']
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use the `split` and `splitlines` methods of strings:

```
names = []
ages = []
for name_age in input.splitlines():
    name, age = name_age.strip().split("\t")
    names.append(name)
    ages.append(age)
```

If you were parsing a more complex format, I would suggest using [the csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), which can also handle tsv… But it seems like it would be a bit overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

Unutbu's answer compressed using a list comprehension:

```
names = [x[0] for x in csv.reader(open(filename,'r'),delimiter='\t')]
ages = [x[1] for x in csv.reader(open(filename,'r'),delimiter='\t')]
```

Answer (score 0):

marvin's answer but without reading the entire file twice

```
data = [ (x[0],x[1]) for x in csv.reader(open(filename,'r'),delimiter='\t')]
```

If you are ok with it being of tuples, instead of two lists

you could still read data into two lists in a single pass and that would be unubtu's answer